# Postgres9.5 Partition

Tags: postgresql

I am not able to do List or Range Partitioning in PostgreSQL 9.5 version?

Below is my query

```
create table measurementlist 
(
    city_id int NOT NULL,
    logdate date,
    peaktemp int,
    unitsales int
)partition by list(city_id);
```

Comment: You need to upgrade to Postgres 12 (or at least 10) if you want list partitioning. 9.5 is  [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/), so you need to plan your upgrade anyway

Comment: Actually, it is still just about supported (until Feb 2021), but if you aren't planning to upgrade soon you need to.

Comment: @RichardHuxton: ah, right. I confused that with 9.4 (but if partitioning is really needed, an upgrade to 12 should be the first anyway)